# ResourceDictionary Linked Resource from another application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to load a resource file that has been linked from another application, the application that holds the file is in a completely different folder when released so I'm not sure if this affects the problem. From the second application I have linked the ResourceDictionary and compile type is set to resource so that file is embedded into the application.

I have then tried different pack://application approaches but it just returns FileNotFoundException. But it shouldn't even return this because the linked resource should be embedded into the second application.

```
var languageDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
languageDictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/First Application;component/en-US.xaml");
```

And I've tried the actual folder structure from the first application

```
var languageDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
languageDictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/First Application;component/Utiltities/Resources/Locales/en-US.xaml");
```

How can I successfully use the linked ResourceDictionary in the second application by embedding it as a resource to the second application?

Cheers.

Comment: Does the resource languageDictionary need to be dynamic i.e. if it changes in the first application, the second application should reflect the changes without the need for recompiling?

Comment: This is what currently happens, I am just trying to load it in the second application which fails. I'm unsure how the two relate?

Comment: IF you really want to embedd it as a resource, you need the source file else add a reference to the first application (and see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

In the second application, the Assembly name is not that of the first application but the second application, with the proper folder structure as well.

```
var languageDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
languageDictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Second Application;componcomponent/Utiltities/Resources/Locales/en-US.xaml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason for the FileNotFoundException is that the ResourceDictionary from the First Application merges further dictionaries and the Source is specified relative to the first application (how in most cases). To use such a dictionary you have to change the source to absolute path (include the assembly)

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/KsWare.Presentation;component/Styles/BusyAdornerVisual.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/OtherVisual.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If the dictionary contains an entry like the "OtherVisual" it is IMHO not possible to merge this dictionary into own dictionary except you can change the source to a absolute path.

*Because this problem I use always absolute path, also if this means more work for me. If there an other solution I would be happy.  :-)*